# Errors while trying to use matlab engine from VC++

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-engine

I'm Using MATLAB R2010a

I used this [this](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jsp/Downloads/MatlabEngine/MatlabEngine.pdf) tutorial in order to call matlab function from C++ and i did every thing said in the tutorial and i compiled the project successfully but when i tried to run it, it requires many dlls which i added them in windows 7 system32:

1. icudt24l.dll
2. icuin24.dll
3. icuio24.dll
4. icuuc24.dll
5. icuuc44.dll
6. libmx.dll
7. libut.dll
8. libz.dll

and I included these files ("libeng.lib" "libmex.lib" "libmx.lib" "libmat.lib") in the project by going to "project properties" -> "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependencies"

and i run again it gives me an error "The procedure entry point mxCreateDoubleMatrix_730 could not be located in the dynamic link library libmx.dll"

So what is this error indicate? and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put those files in the System32 directory. All you need to do is add the path

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin\win64
```

to your system path (google how to do this for your version of windows -- it is subtly different between XP and Vista/7). If you aren't using the 64bit version of matlab, modify the above accordingly.

Also, make sure you are using the right architecture. If you have a 64bit version of Matlab you will need to be using a 64bit compiler.

Comment: I added my Matlab path to the system path but nothing new happened

Comment: I removed all dlls that i added in System 32 and it works fine :)

Comment: Good to hear. :) I forgot to mention one generally has to reboot after updating the system path.